# Maximum number of element IDs you'd want on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, dom

Having trouble searching on this.   The only thing I've found so far was related to a mapping API where (for map markers) JavaScript bogs down badly around 500 IDs.  I'm pretty sure that was related to the particular scripts in use though and not a general rule.

I have a page with a complicated list.   Each item in the list has about 10 distinct IDs on it and there's several JavaScript scripts in play.   The list is paginating and the user has a choice of how many items to show per page.   Considering each item in the list has ~10 IDs, I'm wondering what I should set the maximum number of items per page to (total number of records the user can choose to view at one time on a page).

I mean - aside from increased load times based on the raw number of records, is there a known number of id's where a limit is hit or where CSS/JavaScript performance starts to degrade sharply?

Edit:  Pardon, each 'item' is complex business card (to paint a picture) with three divs in play and a small form.  That's whay each item (record) has about 10 id's.

Comment: One item has several IDs? One element can only have one ID. In general you should think whether it is even necessary to have IDs for those items.

Comment: As little as you need. Having to use several ID's per element is not only incorrect, it implies the way you set your page up is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: All ids have to be unique, and an element can only have one id. Also you may only want to give ids to elements that you need to do things with, either via document.getElementById or for css rules.

Comment: Why do all the elements need IDs? What are you using the IDs for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will find that it will ultimately depend on the user's browser and personal system.

What would probably make the most sense is to do some research on your intended user base, what browser and how much ram they have available.  You can profile your application in your local  environment (and there was already a discussion about doing just [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673707/javascript-memory-usage-debugging-in-chrome-firefox-minefield)).  That would give you an idea of how many system resources you're using versus how much the user has available.

But given the amount of highly graphical javascript stuff going on with HTML5, ect., I would wager you're going to need to have a ridiculous amount of data displaying for the javascript performance to be  your biggest sticking point (at least in the most modern browsers, if you have to support something like IE6, all bets are off).

**Closed the parenthesis, sorry for the willie-giving**

Comment: Unclosed parentheses give me the willies.

Comment: closed corporate enviroment where IE7 is the standard browser (barf), and 90% of everyone is running Windows XP w/ 2 gigs of RAM.  I'm very thankful I do not have to support IE6 (just IE7/IE8).   Thanks for the profiling link - good idea.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't answer my comment and you've already accepted an answer, but I'll give an answer anyway, because I've got a feeling you may not need all the IDs you have.

Let's take following example code:

```
<div id="card-1" onclick="doSomethingWithCard('card-1')">
   <h2 id="card-1-name">John Doe</h2>
</div>
```

Both IDs here can be unnecessary. Many people try to get a reference to an element, that triggered an event, by passing its ID to the event handler and using getElementById. Instead `this` already contains a reference:

```
<div onclick="doSomethingWithCard(this)">
   ...
</div>
```

And once you have that reference, you can use getElementsbyTagName, a CSS selector (usually with a JavaScript Framework/Library like jQuery) or XPath to access the elements inside instead of their separate IDs. This works best if all items have the same inner structur using the appropriate elements (h2, h3, ul, form, etc.) and classes.

jQuery example:

```
function doSomethingWithCard(card) {
   alert($(card).find("h2").text());
}
```

Comment: +1 Excellent said. Better watch out of the number of unnecessary object.